# How to adjust the visibility threshold of a view in Detox

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I have a view that I want to be visible 100% all the time. Right now I assert this by,

```
await expect(element(by.id('testID')).toBeVisible();
```

but the above passes if the visibility is 75% or greater.

How do I enforce that this assertion should only be true if the visibility is 100% only?

Comment: Are you seeing an actual issue here?

Comment: I was looking for this functionality as well. I looked briefly at the implementation below and it seems like we can get it from earl gray, @LeoNatan is this something that wasn't done in detox for reason or you just took earl gray defaults?

Comment: Feel free to submit a PR.

Comment: @max please make a PR. This could be a nice feature.

Comment: PR is here https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/1720